# Angular $resource not working in IE11

Tags: angularjs, get, internet-explorer-11

I'm using angular and I am using $resource to make a request to my controller in MVC. I've ran into a problem where it doesn't work in IE11. Works in chrome and firefox.

I have a homeController.js which with this $scope, it gets called on ng-init when it reaches the div

```
  $scope.getUserShortcuts = function () {
                    $scope.shortcuts = usersService.getUserShortcuts(11); 
                }
```

This calls my userService.js

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

    var myAppModule = angular.module('myApp');

    myAppModule.factory('usersService', ['$resource', function ($resource) {
        console.log("load it");

        // user = controller, getusershortcuts = method, :userId = param
        var userShortcuts = $resource('/user/shortcuts/11', null,
        {
            'get': { method: 'GET', isArray:true }
        });

            getUserShortcuts: function (userId) {
                alert("test");
                return userShortcuts.query(userId);
            }

        };
    }]);
})();
```

My alert gets called but IE11 doesn't even attempt to make a GET.

**This is my error:**

```
TypeError: Object.keys: argument is not an Object
   at extend (http://localhost:45669/Scripts/angular.js:412:7)
   at Resource[name] (http://localhost:45669/Scripts/angular-resource.js:574:13)
   at getUserShortcuts (http://localhost:45669/Scripts/app/services/userService.js:94:17)
   at $scope.getUserShortcuts (http://localhost:45669/Scripts/app/controllers/homeController.js:171:21)
   at $parseFunctionCall (http://localhost:45669/Scripts/angular.js:12331:7)
   at Scope.prototype.$eval (http://localhost:45669/Scripts/angular.js:14383:9)
   at pre (http://localhost:45669/Scripts/angular.js:23851:9)
   at invokeLinkFn (http://localhost:45669/Scripts/angular.js:8213:9)
   at nodeLinkFn (http://localhost:45669/Scripts/angular.js:7701:11)
   at compositeLinkFn (http://localhost:45669/Scripts/angular.js:7075:13) <div class="row" ng-init="getUserShortcuts(11)">
value= undefined
```

Does anyone know what the problem could be?

Comment: Do you have any plnkr/fiddle for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's safe to assume that `userId` is not an object, but it has to be. Furthermore your resource URL has no parameters, so I wonder whether you really want to pass `userId` or the URL is not correct. In any case a correct call would be something like this:

```
getUserShortcuts: function (userId) {
            alert("test");
            return userShortcuts.query({userId: userId});
```

The reason why IE behaves differently is because Chrome obviously has an ES6 compatible implementation of `Object.keys`, which converts `userId` into its object form, whereas an ES5 compatible implementation, like that in IE, throws a `TypeError`. Please note that although Chrome throws no error, it doesn't mean that your code is ok.

Comment: Thanks so much for your post. My method now works and I had no idea about this behaviour with IE.